# Flutter : How to Open endDrawer when app run without pressing any button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to open Drawer when app run without pressing any button.

I used `_scafoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer()` inside initState, it shows null error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make use of `PostFrameCallback` to achieve this.
First, define a global key like this inside your widget but outside the build method.

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

This key will be used to identify the scaffold state and interact with it. Add this key to your scaffold widget inside the build method.

```dart
return Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(),
    key: _scaffoldKey     
)
```

Now, in your initState method, add a `PostFrameCallback` to schedule the opening of the side drawer as soon as the widget tree has finished rendering.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
    });
  }
```

What we are doing here is that we are adding a callback to be called after the build method has executed. We cannot simply call the `_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()` method inside initState as the global key has not been added to the widget tree yet and that's why you are getting the `called on null error`.